# Использования оператора if else. Python

Tags: python

Столкнулся с очень не понятной ситуацией с оператором if-else. Вот мой программный код:

```py
print('Choice koef \n 1: hand 0.8 \n 2: expected value \n 3: min_disp')
k = input('\n your value:')
if (k == '1'):
    choice = 0.8
elif (k == '2'):
    choice = expect_v
elif (choice == '3'):
    choice = min_d
else:
    print("You entered a wrong choice")
```

При выборе 1 или 2 варианта у меня правильно определяет, но когда выбираю 3 вариант выдает мой ELSE.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: заменить `elif (choice == '3'):`   на  `elif k == '3':`   не пробовали ?

Comment: @S.Nick Ой, извиняю. Я не доглядел. Спасибо большое !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятно что и зачем делает код, но в 2м elif у вас проверка значения choice вместо k. Так как choice не был создан во время выполнения данной операции, выдаётся ошибка